# Protractor: create test case scenarios out of spec file

Tags: protractor, jira, document

Currently all test cases in Protractor I must copy/paste into a document (JIRA, ...), for example what I click, enter or interact with and also the assertions. As you can see this is time consuming and I'm wondering if there is there a way to create test scenarios out from Protractor test cases with plugin or something like that?

Comment: You can create a custom jasmine reporter to capture the name and results from each `spec` and log them to a file. So yes you can capture your test case scenarios.  But to capture each action would require a lot more work I think... like creating a helper to wrap around each action you execute.

Comment: https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/custom_reporter.html Are you searching for custom reporter?

Comment: No, I already have the allure reporter, but I can't write test scenario out of it. What I need is something like @Gunderson wrote and unfortunately it seems that it is not yet available. Maybe something in line of reading the spec and taking out describe, it, click, select, ... and expect text, writing it into some sort of document. Like I would take console output to a file, but with more details `protractor conf.js >> test_scenario.txt`.